# How to convert from int to string in objective c: example code

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, int

I am trying to convert from an int to a string but I am having trouble.  I followed the execution through the debugger and the string 'myT' gets the value of 'sum' but the 'if' statement does not work correctly if the 'sum' is 10,11,12.  Should I not be using a primitive int type to store the number?  Also, both methods I tried (see commented-out code) fail to follow the true path of the 'if' statement.  Thanks!

```
int x = [my1 intValue]; 
    int y = [my2 intValue]; 
    int sum = x+y;
    //myT = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];
    myT = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:sum] stringValue];

    if(myT==@"10" || myT==@"11" || myT==@"12")
        action = @"numGreaterThanNine";
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're putting the integer into a string? It would be so much easier to write your test as `if (sum >= 10 && sum <= 12)`

Comment: If the answers bellow confuse you, check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414644/how-to-convert-integer-to-string-in-objective-c-closed

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The commented out version is the more correct way to do this.

If you use the `==` operator on strings, you're comparing the strings' addresses (where they're allocated in memory) rather than the values of the strings. This is very occasional useful (it indicates you have the exact same string object), but 99% of the time you want to compare the values, which you do like so:

```
if([myT isEqualToString:@"10"] || [myT isEqualToString:@"11"] || [myT isEqualToString:@"12"])
```

Comment: Slight typo, a missing : in the 2nd comparison.

Answer (score 186):

If you just need an int to a string as you suggest, I've found the easiest way is to do as below:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberYouAreTryingToConvert]
```

Answer (score 183):

You can use literals, it's more compact.

```
NSString* myString = [@(17) stringValue];
```

(Boxes as a [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and uses its [stringValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/stringValue) method)

Comment: @RavindranathAkila - `stringWithFormat` is more flexible / powerful and should be used in general.  This is just a shortcut if its a simple conversion you are after.

Comment: I prefer this over stringWithFormat, short and concise.

Answer (score 12):

`==` shouldn't be used to compare objects in your `if`. For `NSString` use `isEqualToString:` to compare them.

Answer (score 9):

```
int val1 = [textBox1.text integerValue];
int val2 = [textBox2.text integerValue];

int resultValue = val1 * val2;

textBox3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", resultValue];
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply convert `int` to `NSString`
use :

```
  int x=10;

  NSString *strX=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
```

Answer (score 3):

Dot grammar maybe more swift!

```
@(intValueDemo).stringValue
```

for example

```
int intValueDemo  = 1;
//or
NSInteger intValueDemo = 1;

//So you can use dot grammar 
NSLog(@"%@",@(intValueDemo).stringValue);
```